# What is modules.rst from sphinx-apidoc?

Tags: python-sphinx, documentation-generation, read-the-docs

I am using `sphinx==6.2.1` and `sphinx_rtd_theme==1.3.0`.  I ran `sphinx-apidoc`, and it generated a `modules.rst` that looks like this:

```
package
======

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   package
```

When I go to run `sphinx-build docs docs/_build`, I get a warning:

```
checking consistency... /Users/user/code/package/docs/modules.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
```

I tried deleting `modules.rst`, but it keeps getting regenerated by `sphinx-apidoc`.

How is `modules.rst` supposed to be used, and how should it have been linked with `index.rst`?  What is it's intent within `sphinx-apidoc`?

I am trying to resolve this warning in a Sphinx-standard way.

Comment: That's what [`sphinx-apidoc` is supposed to do](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#description). You need to modify the index files's `toctree` to include `modules.rst` to resolve the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the structure of your documentation. `modules.rst` consists of a toctree that links to each of the rst files associated with each python file. Using `modules.rst`, your documentation *could* look like so:

```
docs/
|_ _build/
|_ _static/
|_ _templates/
|_ source/
|  |_ bar.rst
|  |_ conf.py
|  |_ index.rst
|  |_ foo.rst
|  |_ modules.rst
|  |_ usage.rst
|_ Makefile
|_ make.bat
```

Within index.rst:

```
Welcome to <project> documentation!
==================================

<welcome text>

Contents
--------

.. toctree:: 
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Usage

   usage

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Documentation

   modules
```

This would link to the `modules.rst` file, which would contain both `foo` and `bar`.